# KeyError:'DATABASE_URL' when trying to connect to Heroku Postgress with SQL Alchemy

Tags: heroku, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am running a Flask application trying to connect to Heroku's Postgres via SQLAlchemy.  I am getting an error at this line:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'DATABASE_URL'
```

I have provisioned a database in heroku and in the dashboard on the heroku site it gives a value for DATABASE_URL.  When I type heroku config: get DATABASE_URL I get a resulting url.

When I type in:

```
$python
print os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
```

I get the key error again. DATABASE_URL is not showing up in this os.environ file.  How do I add it?

I am running Windows 10 and tried adding the url as an environmnent variable to Windows 10.  Did not help.

If anyone can shed light on the issue, please respond.

Comment: How did you try to add the DATABASE_URL as an environment variable?

Comment: I went to Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables, and added a new system variable named DATABASE_URL and the hyperlink provided by Heroku.

Comment: I have also tried typing os.eviron['DATABASE_URL'] = <postgres url> and it says "No such file or directory"

Comment: I resolved this bug by adding a line in my python code

Answer (score 2):

I had similiar problem when I added my postgress to wrong app. 
Make sure that you use correct app name when adding your database.

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev --app <app_name>
```

This will add postgress db on your app on heroku and populate DATABASE_URL environment variable.

```
heroku config --app <app_name>
```

This will display your environment variable and it should be there as DATABASE_URL.

```
=== app_name Config Vars
APP_SETTINGS: config.ProductionConfig
DATABASE_URL: postgres://akxmhwgyeysadasdvulk:f8efa996f6c4862acasad2fdd7f59177454b1127251444b1db12e3184f8dd2ca824@ec2-54-225-200-15.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dd09pi392unnk8
```

I know it may sound a bit silly, but I had exactly this problem. 
I have more than one app on heroku and just got confused with all those names.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this bug by adding a line in my main python code

```
os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] = <URL>
```

This added the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by exporting environmental variable `DATABASE_URI`.
(`export DATABASE_URI=<your URI>`)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like none of the answers have helped.

I am going to assume that you are trying to run the app locally using the `heroku local` command.

The environment variables that you access through `heroku config` are only used by the apps that you have deployed by pushing to the heroku repository.

To have your env vars available locally you need to create a local .env file in your root project directory and specify the environment variables there (you can just copy them).

You can find an example and elaboration in Heroku docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#set-up-your-local-environment-variables

*Note: Never specify your environment variables in the code as some people have suggested here. Environment variables sometimes contain sensitive information (eg. passwords, secret keys), if you ever push this data to a public repository, everyone will be able to see it. Heroku environment variables allow you to manage such variables without exposing them in version control, this is also the reason why you should add .env to .gitignore .*